# node mongodb's Connect throws an event emitter when connection is rejected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling

I had an issue with Compose.io not whitelisting my server ip, and it was rejecting my connection to my database. The error mongo was throwing is an EventEmitter and not something of Error type. So it has been very misleading and hard to know what to fix.

my code is:

```
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');

var url = 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@<my-db-url>';
var mongoOptions = {
  db: { safe: true, native_parser: false },
  server: { autoReconnect: true, reconnectTries: Infinity },
  replSet: {}
};

var cb = function (e, r) { console.log('error:', e, 'res', r); };

MongoDB.connect(
  url,
  mongoOptions,
  cb
);
```

The callback returns an error that is an event emitter. Why is that? Is it a bug? If so is it coming from Compose.io or from the node mongo package? Here is the full print of the error (happy to expend some properties):

```
error: EventEmitter {
  id: 2,
  s: 
   { options: 
      { disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        socketOptions: {},
        ssl: true,
        autoReconnect: true,
        reconnectTries: Infinity,
        clientInfo: [Object] },
     bson: {},
     Cursor: 
      { [Function]
        super_: [Object],
        define: [Object],
        INIT: 0,
        OPEN: 1,
        CLOSED: 2,
        GET_MORE: 3 },
     logger: { className: 'Mongos' },
     seedlist: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     haInterval: 10000,
     disconnectHandler: { s: [Object], length: [Getter] },
     index: 0,
     connectOptions: 
      { readPreference: [Object],
        native_parser: false,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
     debug: false,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     clientInfo: 
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v4.6.1, LE, mongodb-core: 2.0.13' } },
  authProviders: 
   { mongocr: { bson: {}, authStore: [] },
     x509: { bson: {}, authStore: [] },
     plain: { bson: {}, authStore: [] },
     gssapi: { bson: {}, authStore: [] },
     sspi: { bson: {}, authStore: [] },
     'scram-sha-1': { bson: {}, authStore: [], id: 1 } },
  state: 'destroyed',
  connectingProxies: [],
  connectedProxies: [],
  disconnectedProxies: 
   [ EventEmitter {
       domain: [Object],
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 7,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       id: 7,
       s: [Object],
       ismaster: null,
       lastIsMasterMS: 10,
       monitoringProcessId: null,
       initalConnect: true,
       wireProtocolHandler: {},
       _type: 'server',
       clientInfo: [Object],
       lastUpdateTime: 0,
       lastWriteDate: 0,
       staleness: 0 },
     EventEmitter {
       domain: [Object],
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 7,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       id: 6,
       s: [Object],
       ismaster: null,
       lastIsMasterMS: 1,
       monitoringProcessId: null,
       initalConnect: true,
       wireProtocolHandler: {},
       _type: 'server',
       clientInfo: [Object],
       lastUpdateTime: 0,
       lastWriteDate: 0,
       staleness: 0 } ],
  authenticating: false,
  index: 0,
  haTimeoutId: 
   { '0': null,
     _called: true,
     _idleTimeout: -1,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idleStart: 359202,
     _onTimeout: null,
     _repeat: null,
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] } },
  ismaster: null,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: 
   { timeout: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     error: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     connect: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     joined: [Function],
     left: [Function],
     reconnect: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the current version of `mongodb` (2.2.11), it passes a [`MongoError`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/MongoError.html) instance when an error occurs. I don't know what _"Compose"_ is.

Comment: compose.io is a database hosting service.

Comment: In that case, I doubt that it's related to that, since you're using the regular MongoDB driver. Which version are you using?

Comment: The latest. I opened a ticket on their jira and they've just fixed it: https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core/commit/aaaa4e45f75e24a5b0cfd8b101e1851c0672a3b9

Comment: good to know :) My server isn't set up for sharding, that's why it probably didn't trigger the error for me.